# Why the zero vector always orthogonal to any other vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Im currently looking at inner products and was wondering why the inner product of any vector with the zero vector is equal to 0. I have researched on this and only found the information that the zero vector is orthogonal to all vectors but no proof alongside.

And hence I was wondering if anyone had any proof as to why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Thanks every for their comment, I was now wondering if anyone could help explain to me why the inner product of $\left \langle M \vec u,\vec v \right \rangle$ = $\left \langle \vec u,M^{T} \vec v \right \rangle$

where M is and $n*n$ square matrix.

Comment: If $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is an inner product on a real vector space, then it is linear in each factor. I.e. $\langle x,\cdot \rangle$ is linear for all $x$ and linear maps map $0$ to $0$, so $\langle x, 0\rangle=0$

Comment: @Taylor S. This is due to the bilinearity of the inner product, which essentially means linearity in each of the two variables. Linearity means additivity (group morphisms in other words) and also homogeneity (commuting with scalar multiplication). In particular, additive group morphisms have the property of sending the source $0$ to the target $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they were extremely useful. I was wondering if you could look at my edit and see if you could help me in any way here at all.

Comment: Your edit is really a separate question, so you should ask it as a separate question. However, $\langle M \vec{u}, \vec{v} \rangle = \langle \vec{u}, M^T \vec{v} \rangle$ is simply the definition of $M^T$.

Comment: sorry about that I will improve on that next time. Can i ask what you mean about it being 'simply the definition of $M^{T}$' as I dont know how to use that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us denote the inner product by $( \cdot|\cdot).$

Then

$$(0|x)=(0x|x)=0(x|x)=0$$

for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it was extremely useful. I was wondering if you could look at my edit and see if you could help me in any way here at all

Answer (score 2):

$$ \langle Mx,y\rangle =(Mx)^{T}y=x^{T}M^{T}y=x^{T}(M^{T}y)=\langle x,M^{T}y\rangle $$

Comment: Thanks can i ask why $\vec x^{T}$ just goes back to $\vec x$?

Comment: @TaylorS. The transpose occurs explicitly when evaluating the inner product: for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the standard inner product on the vector space of column matrices of type $(n, 1)$ -- space symbolised as $\mathscr{M}_{n, 1}(\mathbb{R})$ -- is described as follows: for $X, Y \in \mathscr{M}_{n, 1}(\mathbb{R})$ the inner product $\langle X, Y \rangle$ is equal to the unique element of the matrix $X^{\mathrm{t}}Y$, which is square of order $1$. As a caveat on rigour, most people would write this as $\langle X, Y \rangle=X^{\mathrm{t}}Y$, *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @TaylorS. *(cont.)* however this is not actually correct (it continues to be used however as an *abuse of formal language*), as by definition $\langle X, Y \rangle$ should be a real number whereas $X^{\mathrm{t}}Y$ is a square matrix of order $1$ over $\mathbb{R}$. In general, given a square matrix $(\alpha)$ of order $1$ over some ring, it is not correct to say that $(\alpha)=\alpha$ (it certainly is not a theorem of Set Theory and it is therefore not justified to claim such a relation of equality).